# Dialogs - few questions

Tags: java, android

I have few questions concerning Dialogs in Android as I become a bit confused after reading more and more...

1) In what methods of Activity should I call show() and dismiss() for Dialog? In onResume and onPause? or in onCreate and onDestroy (in Activity)?

2) How to create correctly Dialog which will survive Activity recreation (when changing screen orientation) (I would also expect that all fields will keep their values, ex. for EditText the entered string).

Comment: Please use a `DialogFragment`, as shown in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html, as it will handle all of this for you. The approach that you are discussing has been obsolete for a couple of years.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Althought not sure if since a couple of years ;) Android is quite new and still old approach is in many books. ;) Btw, should I use DialogFragment also for such simple things as ProgressDialog?

Comment: "Althought not sure if since a couple of years" -- `DialogFragment` has been the recommended approach since early 2011, which is "a couple of years". "Btw, should I use DialogFragment also for such simple things as ProgressDialog?" -- the recommendation there is to not use a `ProgressDialog`. Use some other sort of progress indicator, and organize your app such that the user can still get some things done (if not everything) while the background operation is going on. Watch http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEGWcMTxs3I -- avoiding modal loading dialogs is the first anti-pattern presented.

Comment: @ CommonsWare. Thanks a lot for answer. However sometimes it doesnt make sense to do anything in the app until you execute some task, ex. at the beginning I want to present to the user the list of all elements with which he/she can work. Without that list he will not be able to do anything in my app (or almost nothing). Thus a small progress dialog for 2-4 seconds for preparing that list doesn't seem to be a big problem. And least thats my impression. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: I tried to use DialogFragment but still I don't understand one thing concerning the situation what happens when activity controlling dialog is recreated. In all examples I've found DialogFragment is created in onCreate method of activity (it's not the previous object which is re-attached but is created with new MyDialogFragment(). Is that correct? Do you have any good example how activity should use DialogFragment when being recreated?

Comment: DialogFragments are managed for you. You do not need to recreate them. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Dialogs/DialogFragment